# QGIS how to patch a plugin on local machine

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I want to make a minor modification to a plugin (to change a field width in Table Manager).

I edited the .py file and the .ui file and changed what I think are the right numbers but this seems to make no difference when I restart QGIS.

I observed that the .pyc file does not get up updated so I removed it but that does not make any difference.  Is the plugin cached somewhere?  I have been reading the docs for writing plugins and they seem to imply that changing the source and restarting QGIS is all that is necessary.

Of course I may have not understood the code and everything is working exactly as it should!

Comment: Last time I tried it was a matter of removing the pyc (compiled) file and forcing QGIS to compile it again to refresh with the updates.

Comment: Can you add the full path and name of the file you edited? I see 8 .py files and 4 ui files in the folder.

Comment: emacs .qgis/python/plugins/tablemanager/tableManagerUiRename.ui
and .py.  I also removed the .pyc file.
BTW I am using qgis 2.0.1 on a Mac

Comment: If you are running QGIS 2.2, it should be in the .qgis2 folder (at least on Windows). .qgis was used up to QGIS 1.8.

Comment: You are right again. The docs are out of date, surprise ;)
I can now modify the files and they get recompiled as they should but it now gets rather strange.  I changed the field with to 20 and it did not appear to do anything I then spent some time going through the logic of the plugin but could not see where else the limit was enforced.  I then tried to deliberately break it by setting the max length in the ui file to 5 and now it lets me put as much as I like in ????

Comment: I suspect that tableManager_gui.py, line 38 also has to be changed (and maybe more). But I was not successful yet.